# Deleting characters from a list

Tags: python

Hello I have a list and each item in the list has the same characters in the beginning. How do I remove just these characters. "SiteName........................................"

I have tried to use the result.split() it throws an error. Here is my code so far and the output below

```
createlist = open('ztest12.txt', 'r')
result = [line.split(',') for line in createlist.readlines()]
print result




[['Site Name........................................ Denver\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ DenverOutdoor\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Dietzenbach\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ EG3\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Edina\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Hongkong\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Honolulu\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ HooneePlace\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Juarez\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ KansasCity\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Kent\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ LA\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lanham\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lebanon\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lockbourne\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ London\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Mesa\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Minneapolis\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ NewMexico\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ NewYork']]
```

Comment: Is [slicing](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) the string an option for your?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.rsplit()` to accomplish this:

```
>>> data = [['Site Name........................................ Denver\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ DenverOutdoor\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Dietzenbach\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ EG3\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Edina\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Hongkong\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Honolulu\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ HooneePlace\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Juarez\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ KansasCity\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Kent\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ LA\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lanham\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lebanon\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Lockbourne\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ London\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Mesa\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ Minneapolis\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ NewMexico\n'], 
['Site Name........................................ NewYork']]
>>> 
>>> [[s[0].rsplit('.')[-1]] for s in data]
[[' Denver\n'],
 [' DenverOutdoor\n'],
 [' Dietzenbach\n'],
 [' EG3\n'],
 [' Edina\n'],
 [' Hongkong\n'],
 [' Honolulu\n'],
 [' HooneePlace\n'],
 [' Juarez\n'],
 [' KansasCity\n'],
 [' Kent\n'],
 [' LA\n'],
 [' Lanham\n'],
 [' Lebanon\n'],
 [' Lockbourne\n'],
 [' London\n'],
 [' Mesa\n'],
 [' Minneapolis\n'],
 [' NewMexico\n'],
 [' NewYork']]
>>>
```

Perhaps a more robust solution however, would be to use `re.sub()`:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> 
>>> [[sub('Site Name\.*', '', s[0])] for s in data]
[[' Denver\n'],
 [' DenverOutdoor\n'],
 [' Dietzenbach\n'],
 [' EG3\n'],
 [' Edina\n'],
 [' Hongkong\n'],
 [' Honolulu\n'],
 [' HooneePlace\n'],
 [' Juarez\n'],
 [' KansasCity\n'],
 [' Kent\n'],
 [' LA\n'],
 [' Lanham\n'],
 [' Lebanon\n'],
 [' Lockbourne\n'],
 [' London\n'],
 [' Mesa\n'],
 [' Minneapolis\n'],
 [' NewMexico\n'],
 [' NewYork']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just slice them out:

```
with open('ztest12.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [line[50:].rstrip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two option :

- clean one: using regular expression
- quick and dirty one :

  clean = line[50:]   # keep all characters after the 50th

Answer (score 0):

Use "slicing" concept:

```
>>> x = "Hello World!"

>>> x[2:]

'llo World!'

>>> x[:2]

'He'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to split your strings on comma, but there is *no* comma in them. And anyway, this is a job for `replace`, not `split`:

```
createlist = open('ztest12.txt', 'r')
result = [ line.replace('Site Name........................................ ', '') for line in createlist ]
```